# Simple Misunderstanding

Tags: python, python-3.x

What does this program do?

```
def getInput():
    while True:
        x = input("Enter a, b or c: ")
        if not x in "abc":
            print("Not a valid choice.")
    else:
        return x
name = getInput()
```

a) Asks for input until the user enters a, b, or c.

b) Goes into an infinite loop because the condition in the if is always True.

c) Goes into an infinite loop because there is no break statement.

d) Goes into an infinite loop because there is no continue statement.

e) Crashes because the in operator can only be used with lists.

I think it's c or b. But i'm not too sure how to approach it and why it's one over the other. Could anyone be of any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: A homework problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its **C**

> b) Goes into an infinite loop because the condition in the **if** is always True.

Nope, if the user enters a, b, or c then the if isn't true

> c) Goes into an infinite loop because there is no break statement.

Correct, The *while* loop doesn't have any way to exit.